# C++, using #if TRUE conditional directive

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

When using a statement like `#if TRUE`, what should I expect to happen?  An explanation would be very appreciated! I understand how `#if 1` works, but it gives a *completely* different result in my code than using `#if TRUE`. I understand `#if` is a conditional directive, and what that implies; it's just the `TRUE` (or `FALSE`) part that I don't understand. It seems as though using it in this way never executes code following the statement. Here is an example:

```
#if TRUE
     cout << "true" << endl;
#endif

#if FALSE
     cout << "false" << endl;
#endif
```

I never seem to see "true" or "false" printed to screen and using Visual Studio, the inner statement is automatically grayed out.

Comment: You just test if that macros are declared. Usually in WinDef.h they're declared to be used with BOOL.

Comment: Is "TRUE" not a reserved word?

Comment: No, it's just a macro declared with a #define win WinDef.h (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx). The reserved word is "true" (lower case).

Comment: If this is a macro, where would that typically be defined?  I've tried searching all documents with no luck.

Comment: You welcome. See my previous comments, it's defined in the header WinDef.h

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The preprocessor will include/exclude the contents of an `#if #endif` block depending on wether the expression after `#if` evaluates to true or false.

`#if TRUE` will only evaluate to true if

- the macro `TRUE` is defined
- the value of `TRUE` != 0

In your example neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE` are defined so both blocks are false and excluded.

Answer (score 5):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are **macros** in Windows, but declared in `WinDef.h`.

If you include the header, you'll see that `TRUE` is `1` and `FALSE` is `0`. So, the first statement should execute, the second should not.

If you don't include the header, both will be undefined, and neither of the statements will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

To see `true` or `false` printed you need to define them:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 1
```

Now `#if TRUE` and `#if FALSE` will be the same as `#if 1`.

Comment: Modified the answer to define FALSE as 0

Comment: But then the statement after it is no longer true ;).

Comment: @FatalError then use #ifdef FALSE

Comment: @FatalError: Yes. Usually it's defined as 0 but to illustrate how to make both #if statements true I set it to 1.

Comment: Sure, I never said it was "wrong", just saying it was "unusual" to see.

Comment: I appreciate it Sani, this helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not defined by default, and any non-defined preprocessor token is replaced by `0`.

**Full explanation**

The [C++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) 19.1.7 states this about preprocessing directives in the *if-group*:

> Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> - **# if** constant-expression new-line *group-opt*
> - **# elif** constant-expression new-line *group-opt*
>
> check whether the controlling constant expression **evaluates to nonzero**.

(Emphasis added)

The standard 19.1.9 states this about undefined identifiers used in preprocessor directives:

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and evaluations of *defined-macro-expressions* and *has-include-expressions* have been performed, **all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for `true` and `false`, are replaced with the *pp-number* `0`**, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. [ *Note*: An
> alternative token (5.5) is not an identifier, even when its spelling consists entirely of letters and underscores.
> Therefore it is not subject to this replacement. — *end note* ]

(Emphasis added)

Thus, if `TRUE` or `FALSE` are not defined, these are replaced by `0` and the `#if` condition fails. The lowercase variants `true` and `false` are exceptions to this rule and can be used like the C++ language's keywords.
To make the condition true, define the identifiers first, e.g.:

```
#define TRUE
```

or, if you want `TRUE` to be available as an integer value,

```
#define TRUE 1
```

This will work too, although it is not recommended:

```
#define TRUE 5
```

- Note 1: that `#define TRUE 0` *is a definition of `TRUE`* and thus makes the `#if TRUE` condition true.
- Note 2: Some headers (e.g. WinDef.h apparently) include definitions for `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

*Justification for late answer*: This question is being referred to from later duplicate questions and would benefit from having a complete answer with references to the standard.